# nodejs mongodb Gridstore.exist infinite loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs, node-mongodb-native

I am trying to use GridStore of mongodb, I have a wierd infinite loop problem when I try the following code `GridStore.exist(db, req.params.filename, function(err, result){`

The following is the whole code and its debug output

```
var express = require('express'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();

var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/dev_gridfs');
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.errorHandler({dumpExceptions: true, showStack : true}));

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    console.log('main');
    res.send('<img src="/images/test.jpg"/>');
});

var GridStore = mongoose.mongo.GridStore;

app.get('/images/:filename', function(req, res){
    console.log('in get image: ' + req.params.filename);
    GridStore.exist(db, req.params.filename, function(err, result){
        console.log('in gridstore exist');
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500);
            res.send();
        }
        if (result) { 
            console.log('file found');
            //TODO code for sending the file
            res.send('');
        } else {
            res.status(404);
            res.send();
        }
    });
});


app.listen(3000);
console.log('listening on 3000');
```

output printed is

```
main
in get image: test.jpg
```

Versions: [node:v0.8.11, express: 3.0.0rc4, mongoose: 3.2.1]

Any suggestions appreciated. I am not sure if this is a bug with node mongodb driver, I haven't found this as an issue in the driver issue tracker yet.

Comment: Sounds like it might be waiting for `db` to have an open connection.  Are you sure that's opening OK?

Comment: `db` seems alright!, I have put in a save. here is the code `var FileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name : String
});

var File = db.model('File', FileSchema);

app.get('/images/:filename', function(req, res){
    console.log('in get image: ' + req.params.filename);
    
    var f = new File({name: req.params.filename});
    f.save(function(err){
  if (!err) console.log('filename saved');
 });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake! GridStore expects MongoDB DB object and NOT Mongoose DB object. made the following code change and everything else works as expected!

changed the following line shown in code above

```
var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/dev_gridfs');
```

as

```
var mongooseDb = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/dev_gridfs');
var db = mongooseDb.db;
```